# Canceling filewatcher run by TimerTask after receiving websocket message in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I've been coding around in circles trying to work this one out, new to java and have been lurking here to find things out for a while but I really can't get passed this one. I adapted some code by Desmond Shaw (http://www.codepool.biz/how-to-implement-a-java-websocket-server-for-image-transmission-with-jetty.html) to create a websocket to tranfer jpg images from a server to remote clients. I want to send files from the server to the browser windows of connected clients when some specific files on the server change (they are pages of music scores that are created using Max/MSP in real-time), but I don't seem to be able to cancel the timers I'm creating to watch these files in my home directory for changes.

More specifically I'm sending messages from the remote browser clients (through javascript buttons operated by the users) over a websocket connection to specify which of the files they wish to see updated on their screen (i.e part one, which refers to a file on the server called "1.png" and is the violin part, or part 2 which is the server file "2.png" and is the cello part etc). This is then used within the websocket handler running on my server to send the right files to that client when a filewatcher detects they have changed on the server. I can get everything going except stopping the timers running the filewatchers, when a different part is requested by the client (say the violin player wants to look at the cello players part). Below is the method I have edited to respond to the messages from the clients:

```
@OnWebSocketMessage  //part request from websocket client (remote browser)
public void onMessage( String message) {
    System.out.println("Message: '" + message + "' received");
    sFclient = message;
    if (sFclient == "1" || sFclient == "2" || sFclient == "3" || sFclient == "4") {
        System.out.println("Part " + sFclient + " joined");
        }
    else {
    sFclientOut = 0;
    }
}

public void onChange( File file ) {
        System.out.println( "File "+ file.getName() +" has changed!" );         
        TimerTask task = new FileWatcher(new File("/Users/benedict/" + message + ".png")) {                 
                try {           
                    File f = new File("/Users/benedict/" + sFclient + ".png");
                    BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(f);
                    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    ImageIO.write(bi, "png", out);
                    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(out.toByteArray());
                    mSession.getRemote().sendBytes(byteBuffer);
                    out.close();
                    byteBuffer.clear();
                    }
                    catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }                       

        Timer timer1 = new Timer(); {
        timer1.schedule(task , new Date(), 20 );
        if (sFclientOut == 0){
            task.cancel();
            timer1.cancel();
        }
        }

}
```

I had it working mostly using an if statement which I've now abandoned but have been editing and now it doesn't make as much sense probably. Any help at all would be appreciated, but my main question is should I be trying to cancel the threads handling the timertasks or use a completely different approach altogether like a switch statement for example. I have tried sending a message before every new message from the browsers ("0") to cancel the old threads but the Timertasks just don't start at all, which I think is because that cancels the timertask and doesn't let it run again?

Thanks,
Benedict

Comment: I should mention that timertask calls an object called filewatcher which scans the specified folder for changes

Comment: also the filewatcher code is from here http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0490.html

Answer (score 0):

Ok here's the final working solution, I just had to cancel the tasks based on a message from the clients (in this case a 0)

```
else if (message.equals("0")) {
    zerocounter = zerocounter + 1;
        if (zerocounter >= 2) {
            task.cancel();
        }
```